# How can I exclude one specific class by css?

Tags: css, angularjs, tabs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have nested tab. You can access from (http://plnkr.co/edit/QbMjutwEIRfHYpgELuIz?p=preview)

I want to apply this class to only `.verticaltab` class so I wrote css like that:

CSS:

```
.nav-tabs {
    float: left;
    }
.verticaltab:not(.horizantaltab) .nav-tabs li.active>a{
    background: antiquewhite;
}
```

HTML:

```
<tabset vertical="true" type="tabs" class="vertical">
    <tab>
        <tab-heading>A</tab-heading>
        <tabset class="horizantaltab">
            <tab><tab-heading>SONY</tab-heading></tab>
            <tab><tab-heading>VESTEL</tab-heading></tab>
        </tabset>
    </tab>
    <tab>
        <tab-heading>B</tab-heading>
        <tabset class="horizantaltab">
            <tab><tab-heading>SONY</tab-heading></tab>
            <tab><tab-heading>VESTEL</tab-heading></tab>
        </tabset>
    </tab>
</tabset>
```

But it does not work. Could you please help me. Also horizontal tab applies background color.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a link to an example, if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Comment: I don't see any class="nav-tabs" in the html

Comment: It s angular tab so it creates autamatically with nav nav-tabs nav-stacked classes. You can run plunker and inspect.

Comment: Maybe I can write css for horizantal class to owerwrite them . But it s not good way.

Comment: Your HTML says `class="vertical"` but your CSS says `.verticaltab`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the Angular output correctly, as you had it, the cascade applies to all (`:not(.horizantaltab)` is never matched). Try:

```
.verticaltab > .nav-tabs li.active > a {
    background: antiquewhite;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[I am borrowing fromthe MDN site (Mozilla Developer Network)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:not) to show that :not tells an attribute to specifically not apply via another selector or class, but that not class has to be declared somewhere else with attributes or it will have no effect on the page:

```css
p:not(.classy) { color: red; }
body :not(p) { color: green; }
```

```html
<p>Some text.</p>
<p class="classy">Some other text.</p>
<span>One more text<span>
```

But you declare a .nav-tabs in css but not html so that class will never apply. What exactly are you trying to do? If you want to style something, style that rule, then use :not to create your exception to the rule.